# Exhaling properly underwater?

Tags: swimming, breathing

The thing I struggle most with when trying to lap swim is getting the breathing right. After blowing my air out underwater, the breath I take in above water feels very shallow and I don't get much actual air out of it. After two or three inhales, I usually have to stop swimming and catch my breath.

How do I make sure I'm exhaling properly underwater? What is it I might be doing wrong?

Comment: See how to [properly breathe while swimming freestyle](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/428/how-do-i-properly-breathe-while-swimming-freestyle).  There is a link to an article about exhaling.